# How to make a code that shakes the camera of the player

Tags: lua, roblox, luau

I tried to make a code that's shake the camera player when a RemoteEvent is fired by a key on the keyboard. But it didn't worked. I tried to use the CameraOffset but didn't worked too. How can i make this code without using the CameraShakeModule??? Any sugestion??? Code below:

```
local ts = game:GetService("TweenService")
local replicated = game.ReplicatedStorage
local powers = replicated.Powers
local Info = TweenInfo.new(2, Enum.EasingStyle.Quad, Enum.EasingDirection.InOut)
local ss = game:GetService("ServerStorage")
local FireWind = ss.FireWind:Clone()

powers.GiantFire.OnServerEvent:Connect(function(Player, Hit)
    local char = Player.Character or Player.CharacterAdded:Wait()
    local SuperFireSphere = Instance.new("Part")
    local hrpp = char.PrimaryPart
    local currentcam = workspace.Camera
    currentcam.CameraSubject = char.Humanoid
    currentcam.CameraType = Enum.CameraType.Scriptable
    SuperFireSphere.Shape = Enum.PartType.Ball
    SuperFireSphere.Material = Enum.Material.Neon
    SuperFireSphere.BrickColor = BrickColor.new("New Yeller")
    SuperFireSphere.Anchored = true
    SuperFireSphere.CanCollide = false
    task.wait(.2)
    local bv = Instance.new("BodyVelocity")
    bv.MaxForce = Vector3.new(math.huge, math.huge, math.huge)
    bv.Velocity = CFrame.lookAt(hrpp.CFrame.Position, Hit.Position).LookVector * 150
    hrpp.Position += Vector3.new(0, 50 , 0)
    hrpp.Anchored = true
    SuperFireSphere.Parent = workspace
    FireWind:SetPrimaryPartCFrame(hrpp.CFrame)
    FireWind.Parent = workspace
    SuperFireSphere.Position = char.PrimaryPart.Position + Vector3.new(0,15,0)
    for i = 1, 15 do
        task.wait(.1)
        SuperFireSphere.Size += Vector3.new(2,2,2)
    end
    for i, parts in pairs(FireWind:GetDescendants()) do
        if parts:IsA("MeshPart") then
            local tween = ts:Create(parts, Info, {Transparency = 1})
            tween:Play()
        end
    end
    for i = 1,20 do
        local x = math.random(-100, 100)/100
        local y = math.random(-100, 100)/100
        local z = math.random(-100, 100)/100
        char.Humanoid.CameraOffset = Vector3.new(x,y,z)
        print(i)
        task.wait(.5)
    end
    local FireParticle = ss.Fire:Clone()
    FireParticle.Parent = SuperFireSphere
    SuperFireSphere.Anchored = false
    bv.Parent = SuperFireSphere
    task.wait(2)
    hrpp.Anchored = false
    FireWind.Parent = ss
    for i, parts in pairs(FireWind:GetDescendants()) do
        if parts:IsA("MeshPart") then
            parts.Transparency = 0
        end
    end
    task.wait(5)
    SuperFireSphere:Destroy()
end)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is that you made the `CameraType` scriptable, with it scriptable, the character's `Humanoid` no longer has control of it. Remove the lines that make the `CameraType` scriptable and it will solve your issue.

Comment: Didn't worked, i tried without the CameraType and CameraSubject and not setting the camera variable. Only the CameraOffset

Comment: @takezo is this in a local script and is the rest of the code running? also try using just `wait()` instead of `task.wait()`

Comment: I made the code fire a Client Event, then it worked. Tysm, i used a localscript to make the screen shake when the RemoteEvent fires the Client